# How to properly process regex match

Tags: python, regex

I have strings that come from outside to my application and may look like these with quotes:

```
Prefix content. "Some content goes here". More contents without quotes.
Prefix content. "Another "Additional" goes here". More contents without quotes.
Prefix content. "Just another "content". More contents without quotes.
```

The key note is that the strings come with quotes and I need to process these quotes properly. Actually I need to catch all the content inside quotes. I tried patterns like `.*(".*").*` and `.*(".+").*` but they seem to catch only content between two closest quotes.

Comment: It is unclear to me exactly which content you wish to capture. For example in line #3 what would you like to match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just want everything from the first quote to the last quote, even if there are other quotes between.  This should suffice:

```
".*"
```

The leading and trailing `.*` in your regex were never needed, and the leading one was distorting your results.  It would initially consume the whole input, then back off just far enough to let the rest of the regex match, meaning the `(".*")` would only ever match the last two quotes.

You don't need the parentheses, either.  The part of the string you're after is now the entire match, so you can retrieve it with `group(0)` instead of `group(1)`.  If there may be newlines in the string and you want to match those, too, you can change it to:

```
(?s)".*"
```

The `.` metacharacter normally doesn't match newlines, but `(?s)` turns on `DOTALL` mode for the rest of the regex.

---

EDIT: I forgot to mention that you should be using the `search()` method in this case, not `match()`.  `match()` only works if the match is found at the very beginning of the input, as if you had added the start anchor (e.g., `^".*"`).  `search()` performs a more traditional regex match, where the match can appear anywhere in the input. ([ref](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#module-contents))

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain what you're trying to extract, so I'm guessing. I'd suggest using `partition` and `rpartition` string methods.

Does this do what you want?

```
>>> samples = [
...   'Prefix content. "Some content goes here". More contents without quotes.',
...   'Prefix content. "Another "Additional" goes here". More contents without quotes.',
...   'Prefix content. "Just another "content". More contents without quotes.',
... ]
>>> def get_content(data):
...   return data.partition('"')[2].rpartition('"')[0]
...
>>> for sample in samples:
...   print get_content(sample)
...
Some content goes here
Another "Additional" goes here
Just another "content
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I now see the another answer and I might have misunderstood your question.

Try changing this

```
.*(".+").*
```

to

```
.*?(".+?")
```

The `?` will make the search non-greedy and will stop as soon as it will find the next matching character (i.e. quote). I also removed the .* at the end as it would match rest of the string (regardless of the quotes). If you want to match empty quotes as well just change the `+` to `*`. Use `re.findall` to extract all the content from within the quotes.

PS: I assumed your last line is wrong as it doesn't have matching quotes.

Comment: A non-greedy match will fail lines 2 and 3, if I've understood his goal correctly

Comment: @Nate I just removed the .* at the end. re.findall works fine for the second line, the third line doesn't have matching quotes so I assumed it was just pasted wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you wanted to achieve.
finditer method from re module may be helpful here.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''Prefix content. "Some content goes here". More contents without quotes.
...     Prefix content. "Another "Additional" goes here". More contents without quotes.
...     Prefix content. "Just another "content". More contents without quotes.'''
>>> pattern = '".+?"'
>>> results = [m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(pattern, s)]
>>> print results
['"Some content goes here"', '"Another "', '" goes here"', '"Just another "']
```